# HTTPS request on AWS Fargate task

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, https, aws-fargate

I need an ephemeral/temporary FLask app for each visitor of my web app. This Flask app can be deployed to AWS Fargate. I can create a new task on-demand, using AWS Lambda, each time to reduce AWS cost as much as possible. I do not need any Load Balancer with this architecture.

My issue is that I need HTTPS requests to the Flask app/Fargate task and I do not understand how to do it. A self-signed certificate does not seem to comply with modern browsers but how to attach a certificate to each Fargate public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Buy a domain. Once you have **your own domain**, you can get free public SSL certificate using AWS ACM. Once you have this, you can deploy the cert on ALB which fronts your Fargate service.
2. Setup a **CloudFront** (CF) distribution in front of your ALB. Default CF endpoint that you will get will be HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks. I have a domain but I did not see the point of having an ALB since I do not need balancing. It seems a heavy (but maybe necessary) solution simply to reach a dedicated Fargate task.

Comment: @ABotella You need ALB. ECS fargates do not have static IP addresses. The only way to reliably exposes your ECS service to the internet is through ALB.

Comment: thanks again. I need to look into ALB. Can I run Fargate tasks on-demand the same way?

Comment: @ABotella If you don't need static public IP you don't need ALB. Not sure how it would work with ALB if you had only temporary ecs services. Guess you would have to add them to ALB using your lambda.

Comment: Is ts best to use ALB or another way, (like api gateway or even lambda) to forward all the requests to each known fargate task ?

Comment: @ABotella ALB will be the easiest to setup with HTTPS. AWS ACM can't be used wihout ALB, so you need to get an external valid SSL cert as well.